# applying external .css for html created using XSL from asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, xml, xslt

My scenario is, when a user clicks on a "button" from webform i have to create html file [using xsl tranformation of xml] and open it as a pop upwindow in client side.

xml transformation is done and i am ready with html.
I have created PopUpReport.aspx and popping up this page using below code.

```
Session["reportHtml"] = htmlReport;//this contains the transformed html
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string),
 "Showing Modalpopup", "window.open('PopUpReport.aspx',  'Report', 
'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');",true);
```

and inside PopUpReport.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(Session["reportHtml"]);
    }
```

now my problem is,

i have a seperate .css file and which needs to be applied to the above HTML page, how should I link that in html?

specifying below in xsl file is not working.

and i dont want inline style as it contains huge lines of code.

is there any way to achieve this? should we use themes for this PopUpReport.aspx page? please help me...

Answer (score -1):

In the .aspx file you are calling, link the CSS file in the head like this:

```
<link href="your.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html for more details.

Comment: thanks for reply.. i was trying to inject the .css file to the html using string.replace. now i have changed my implementation and it started working fine.